# SQL stored Procedure With Cursor to update a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, cursor, ora-00942

I am trying to update a table using stored procedure but it is giving out an error,Please explain what is the reason. THIS is the code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure UpdateItem
   ( ITEM_TYPE_NAME IN varchar2 )
IS
    V_TABLE_NAME    VARCHAR2(100);
    V_R_TABLE_NAME  VARCHAR2(100);
    V_SQL_STMT     VARCHAR2(1000);

   cursor c1 is
    select C.RTARGETITEMID ||'#'||C.VERSIONID||'#'||trim(p.CREATEUSERID)||'#bsacm#CBR.CLLCT001# #/icmrm/ICMResourceManager#727665642020202020202020#2509.000000#9080#1#ICMNLSDB# #201#1#' as ITEM_REF, C.ITEMID as ITEM_ID 
    from  V_TABLE_NAME  C, V_R_TABLE_NAME R 
    where C.TIEFLAG = 0 and C.ITEMID=R.ITEMID;


BEGIN

select TABLE_NAME into V_TABLE_NAME 
from user_indexes 
where INDEX_NAME = (SELECT distinct c.INDEXNAME
                    FROM ICMSTNLSKEYWORDS k, ICMSTCOMPDEFS d, ICMSTTEXTINDEXES c
                    WHERE k.KEYWORDCLASS = 2 AND k.KEYWORDCODE = d.ITEMTYPEID AND d.COMPONENTTYPEID = c.COMPONENTTYPEID AND k.KEYWORDNAME = ITEM_TYPE_NAME);

select TABLE_NAME into V_R_TABLE_NAME 
from user_constraints 
where CONSTRAINT_NAME in (select distinct R_CONSTRAINT_NAME 
                          from user_constraints 
                          where TABLE_NAME in (select TABLE_NAME 
                                              from user_indexes 
                                              where INDEX_NAME = (SELECT distinct c.INDEXNAME
                                                                  FROM ICMSTNLSKEYWORDS k, ICMSTCOMPDEFS d, ICMSTTEXTINDEXES c
                                                                  WHERE k.KEYWORDCLASS = 2 AND k.KEYWORDCODE = d.ITEMTYPEID AND d.COMPONENTTYPEID = c.COMPONENTTYPEID AND k.KEYWORDNAME=ITEM_TYPE_NAME)));

open c1;
fetch c1 into V_SQL_STMT;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE V_TABLE_NAME set TIEFLAG = ''1'',TIEREF = c1.ITEM_REF WHERE ITEMID = ITEM.ITEM_ID';

commit;

close c1;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

And this is the error:

> Error(9,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement
>   ignored Error(10,28): PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What is the code supposed to do ? What is cursor c1 supposed to be about ?

Answer (score 0):

As V_TABLE_NAME is a variable, you need to concatenate the variable in your string. The way you did it assumes there is a table named *V_TABLE_NAME* in your system.

As far as I can tell you need to change the line:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE V_TABLE_NAME set TIEFLAG = ''1'',TIEREF = c1.ITEM_REF WHERE ITEMID = ITEM.ITEM_ID';
```

to

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '||V_TABLE_NAME||' set TIEFLAG = ''1'',TIEREF = c1.ITEM_REF WHERE ITEMID = ITEM.ITEM_ID';
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, after updating the code i get the folowin error Error(9,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(10,28): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist